# How to do secure, automatic installation on mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install mysql 5.7 entirely through the use of a script. This is causing a few headaches as I want to avoid having to respond manually to the various prompts during installation.

I've managed to get to the point where I can install mysql automatically *and* run the `mysql_secure_installation` script using the following code:

```
# Add MySQL software repo
cd /tmp
curl -OL https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*

# Install mysql
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Clean up install files
rm mysql-apt-config*

# Install "expect"
sudo apt-get -qq install expect > /dev/null

# Generate an expect script
tee ~/secure_mysql.sh > /dev/null << EOF

  spawn $(which mysql_secure_installation)

  # Would you like to setup the validate Password Plugin?
  expect "Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No:"
  send "n\r"

  # Please set the password for root here.
  expect "New password:"
  send "MyPass\r"

  expect "Re-enter new password:"
  send "MyPass\r"

  # Remove anonymous users
  expect "Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Disallow remote root login
  expect "Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Remove test DB?
  expect "Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Reload privilege tables
  expect "Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect eof
EOF

# This runs the "mysql_secure_installation" script which removes insecure defaults.
sudo expect ~/secure_mysql.sh

# Cleanup
rm -v ~/secure_mysql.sh
```

Everything looks like it has worked okay, but afterwards I can still log in as a root user without a password. I've tried flushing privileges and restarting mysql but neither helped. I've also tried running `mysql_secure_installation` manually but I have the same issue (everything looks as though it worked but then I can still get in with no password).

It seems like it may be connected to initially installing mysql without a password but I can't understand why that would later prevent me from setting up a root password.

Anybody else encountered this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. For whatever reason, the secure installation script just doesn't seem to set a root password if there isn't one there already, so the trick to it is to set a password as part of the mysql-server installation using `debconf-set-selections`.

This also requires an update to the expect script as the prompts will be slightly different when a password has already been set. My script ended up as follows:

```
MYSQL_PASS="MyPass"

# Add MySQL software repo (possibly unnecessary for you, but I want to set up group replication later)
cd /tmp
curl -OL https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*

# Install mysql
apt-get update

# You may have to change these two lines
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password $MYSQL_PASS" | debconf-set-selections
echo "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password $MYSQL_PASS" | debconf-set-selections

apt-get install -y mysql-server

# Clean up install files
rm mysql-apt-config*

# Install "expect"
apt-get -qq install expect > /dev/null

# Generate an expect script
tee ~/secure_mysql.sh > /dev/null << EOF

  spawn $(which mysql_secure_installation)

  # Enter the password for user root
  expect "Enter the password for user root:"
  send $MYSQL_PASS
  send "\r"

  # Would you like to setup the validate Password Plugin?
  expect "Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No:"
  send "n\r"

  # Change the password for root?
  expect "Change the password for root ? ((Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "n\r"

  # Remove anonymous users
  expect "Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Disallow remote root login
  expect "Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Remove test DB?
  expect "Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  # Reload privilege tables
  expect "Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) :"
  send "y\r"

  expect eof
EOF

# Run Expect script.
# This runs the "mysql_secure_installation" script which removes insecure defaults.
sudo expect ~/secure_mysql.sh

# Cleanup
rm -v ~/secure_mysql.sh # Remove the generated Expect script
```

---

## Determining the correct debconf-set-selection commands

The easiest way to do this is to set up a testing VM and do a manual, trial installation of mysql on it. Once that's installed, run `sudo apt install debconf-utils`.

Next search the configuration database with

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep mysql
```

You're looking for the options with password in the final field. For me these were:

```
mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password
mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password
```

But there are a lot of different commands floating around the internet so yours may be different. Replace the relevant parts in my script and you should (hopefully) be good to go.